# RCP JUnitPluginTest, logback and slf4

Tags: eclipse, junit, rcp, logback

I've created a RCP plugin inside which I've used logback with slf4 that are part of eclipse platform.

I've also created a plugin test that I'm launching by *Run As->Junit Plugin Test* (see the picture below).

[image: Run As]

Unfortunatelly I'm getting this error

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

It seems to be a classpath error but I don't really know why; Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The problem seemed to be in a sort of incompatibility of slf4/logback plugins distributed in eclipse platform (in my case Eclipse Indigo R2 32bit).

I solved unistalling those plugins and following the instructions in

[logback doc](http://logback.qos.ch/beagle/index.html)